# JSON results from MVC3 are undefined

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to take the JSON results from an MVC3 action and push it into a table row but the values are all undefined. How can I properly parse the JSON results from a JQuery ajax request?

This is the MVC3 action method

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public JsonResult GetImageDetails(int id)
    {
        Image img = db.Images.First(i => i.ID == id);
        return Json(img);
    }
```

This is the JQuery to handle the results once they return

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Controller/GetImageDetails",
        data: "id=" + id,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $.map(data, function (item) {
                $('#tblImages > tbody > tr:first').before("<tr><td>ID:" + item.ID + "</td><td><img src='" + item.ThumbURL + "' alt='" + item.Name + "'/></td></tr>");
            });
        },
        error: function (obj) {

        }
    })
```

The result are rows with nothing but undefined. I get the same number of rows as there are properties in the object I'm returning so I'm sure I'm just not handling that JSon result correctly. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to handle that JSon result please? Also are there any browser support issues with the suggested approach? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your `Image` class look like? What do you see in Firebug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use $.map on a single object. I think this will end up iterating through the property keys of that object. Try just accessing the object properties off the data object

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Controller/GetImageDetails",
        data: "id=" + id,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
                $('#tblImages > tbody > tr:first').before("<tr><td>ID:" + data.ID + "</td><td><img src='" + data.ThumbURL + "' alt='" + data.Name + "'/></td></tr>");
        },
        error: function (obj) {

        }
    })
```

Comment: That worked! Your the man! I have to wonder though if the change to the GET also made it work too? That is also still in place thanks to Jesse's suggestion. Any pointers and best practice idea's are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think Get or POST would both work. If you have sensitive information or a massive amount of information you should send it via post. Submitting a form for example should be POST. GET is often used to get an entities information. In cases like that you would give it some Id right in the URL like http://urlToMyAction?Id=1. Also, I'm not sure if the data property would be ignored if you did a GET type request or if jquery is smart enough to tack it on to the url in the form expected with a GET request

Comment: I appreciate your input. I'm sensitive to the differences between get and post because of the security implications but your absolutely right they both work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried performing a get on your action vs a post?

eg:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public JsonResult GetImageDetails(int id)
{
    Image img = db.Images.First(i => i.ID == id);
    return Json(img, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a single image from your action, but treating it as an array client-side. Why? Have you tried examining the `data` and seeing what is actually in it?
I am surprised `map()` call works at all.

Also FYI `map()` is meant for transforming elements of given array. If you are not returning a value from your callback, then you should be using `each()` instead.

Comment: Instead of map() how should I get at that data instead? I was hoping I could just do data.ID for example but that is also undefined. each() in place of map() also gives me just undefined.